# MongoDB Add custom field on insert OR JSON add custom key:value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hya!

Long story short.

What I'm using:

- node.js
- mongodb
- mongoose

### **Is there any way to add custom field to mongo collection on insert?**

I insert some amount of data (~35Mb nothing serious) every 30 mins via JSON file and I would like to add a custom field which is static for every document that have been inserted at one time.

(actually this a timestamp which is already generated by another server, unfortunately mongodb already reserved "timestamps"  for it's own inner usage so that's why I'm here)

My code looks something like these

```
...
var toomuchJSONdata = [{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
 }
 {
    "name":"Carl",
    "age":25,
}{
    "....":"....",
    "....":"....",
}];
...
to-my.collection.insertMany(toomuchJSONdata)
...
```

So what's the best/easiest way to solve my problem? Or I'm moving in the wrong direction and it's much easier and better to add a custom "key":"value" for every JSON object? Like:

```
 var toomuchJSONdata = [{
 "name":"John",
 "age":30,
 "customkey":"customvalue"   
 }
```

By the way, how's better to store data in Mongo as Date or timestamp? (I'd like to store it, because I need to $aggregate data in future)
What I have already done (..and still doing):

- Experimented with .insert and mongoose.model
- overlooked docs for mongoose/mongodb/native-mongodb-for node.js
- I'm already google-coding for 3+ hours and still can't fix my problem.

Comment: Can you post the attempts you've made? so far all I see is the JSON data, not the attempts you've made to put it into the DB.  Adding a field is pretty trivial, so I'm not sure what's tripping you up without seeing that.

Comment: Actually I have tried something like these: 
to-my.collection.insertMany(toomuchJSONdata,[{"key":"value") //via mongoose and various different drives in various different methods. Code works fine and does insert job well. I know that adding a custom field isn't a big deal for a stackoverflow question. But i'm requiring to do it only to all documents in collection that have been inserted in one moment in time. Unfortunately I have found docs only hat make this possible to all documents in collection, but not all those that I have .inserted recently

Comment: Can this help you ? [db.collection.updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) or [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Comment: The only "hack" that I have found and which is already working for now, is to rename one of unnecessary fields and insert my "timestamp" data in it. You are absolutely right that problem isn't in mongo, it more about JSON around here. That file always changes every 30 mins, so I don't even know how much documents (strings) will be imported for the next time (that's it I can't solve this problem via _id)

Comment: @stackoverYC I'm already using $set for now, but is there any way to filter all recently added/inserted (for 1 min ago for example) with db.collection.updateMany()? Because _Id is not an option in my case (JSON generated not by me but by another server)

Comment: Why not just transform the objects in memory?  Use Array.map to create a new collection of the documents with the added field(s) before doing updatemany?

Comment: @Paul you wouldn't believe me, but this is what I'm doing right now. (just checking it) I'm 99% sure that's will fix my problem (but I haven't mention that I'm needed to async .insert 20+ JSONs..so that's another story)

Comment: Vote for @Paul, too. Or try this [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)

Comment: @stackoverYC y, Javascript saves our souls (once again). (I'm already using this in my recent .js (with table-to-json) which parsing html body and .replace /all-useless-stuff/g, "") I though mongodb could do some of this stuff for js. Guess I should mark this question as solved.

Javascript (1) > MongoDB (0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL:DR In my case I solve this problem with this code which modifies my JSON data before .insering it to MongoDB:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(body).files;
    var ts = (jsonObject[0].lastModified); //form timestamp TODO if ts updated too long reresh timer for query
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        request(jsonObject[0].url, function(error, response, body){
            var MarketData = JSON.parse(body).auctions;
            MarketData.map(function (MarketData) {
                MarketData.lastModified = ts;
            });
```

Thanks to [@Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53788/paul) and [@stackoverYC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4680681/stackoveryc) for inspiring me.

The reason why I can't just use $aggregate via mongoose (or other mongodb driver) because "timestamp" field is already reserved by mongodb for its own "inner-usage". So I call my new field as "lastModified"